# BigQuery how to omit some columns writing if datatype not fits in Java

Tags: google-bigquery

I received the error message `BigQuery response error: \n[BigQueryError{reason=invalid, location=meta.fields.contacts.fields.userid.options[0], message=This field: options is not a record.}]`because I try to write a record to BigQuery column that defined as String.
Can I continue to write my data without recreation the my BigQuery table with updated schema?

**I am OK with ignoring writing to `options` column if data not fits datatype. Put null or anything if error in this column. Just write all data to all another columns. Is it possible?**

My code:

```
public void tableInsertRows(String datasetName, String tableName, Map<String, Object> rowContent)
            throws ServerException, IOException {
        BigQuery bigquery = getBigQuery();
        TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
        InsertAllResponse response =
                bigquery.insertAll(
                        InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
                                .addRow(rowContent)
                                .build());
        if (response.hasErrors()) {
            for (Map.Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
                throw new ServerException("BigQuery response error: \n" + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is straightforward.
I just removed problematic and not important field `options` from my object I want to write to BigQuery

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) //ADDED
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "label",
    "name",
    "type"
    //,"options" //REMOVED
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class UserId__1 {

    @JsonProperty("label")
    private String label;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;
    //@JsonProperty("options") //REMOVED
    //private List<Object> options; //REMOVED

}
```